# How can I load ply file in arcore instead of glb

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform, ply

I need to load .ply file instead of glb. Can anyone help me out with ways to load ply 3d models in arcore. i have attached a sample ply file here

Ply file : [1679314339602.ply](https://unitear.s3.amazonaws.com/xr_assist/models/user_1019/1679314339602.ply)